# How do I enable Intellisense for imported SCSS classes in TypeScript with Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass

I've imported the module SCSS file into my component, but when I try to type those classes Intellisense doesn’tshow any of available classes:

[image]

I have the *global.d.ts* file inside the *src* folder which looks like this:

```js
declare module '*.scss' {
  interface IClassNames {
    [className: string]: string
  }
  const classNames: IClassNames;
  export = classNames;
}
```

Also I have Webpackthe loader for (S)CSS:

```js
const cssLoader = {
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: [
      isDev ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: {
            auto: (resPath: string) => Boolean(resPath.includes('.module.')),
            localIdentName: isDev
              ? '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
              : '[hash:base64:8]',
          },
        },
      },
      'sass-loader',
    ],
  }
```

How can I make Intellisense show me those classes inside my *module.scss* file?